# Why installed MongoDB driver is not shown in a phpinfo file?

Tags: php, apache, mongodb, ubuntu, php-mongodb

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, PHP 5.5.13 (cli) and  Apache/2.4.10. I installed Mongodb 2.6.4. It's working fine. Then i installed PHP-MongoDB driver. It got installed but is not showing in phpinfo(). When i execute php file with mongodb, i get the following error:

```
 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mongo.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/mongo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file   or directory in Unknown on line 0
 [Sun Aug 24 11:48:39.403845 2014] [:error] [pid 3008] [client 127.0.0.1:58857] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MongoClient' not found in /var/www/PHP/php-mongo/testingmongodb.php on line 3, referer: http://localhost/PHP/php-mongo/
```

I installed PHP Mongodb driver as follows:

```
 sudo pecl install mongo
```

There are two php.ini so i added

```
 extension=mongo.so
```

in both php.ini

```
 /etc/php.ini
 /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Then, restarted apache2

I also tried manual way.

```
unzip php_mongo-1.5.1.zip
cd mongodb-php-driver
phpize
./configure
sudo make install
```

While excuting phpize, i got the following error:

```
 Cannot find config.m4. 
 Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module
```

I also create a file /etc/php5/conf.d/mongo.ini and added "extension=mongo.so" but, still nothing is happening. I can't figure it out what's happening. Please help me in this.

Comment: Did you get any errors installing via `pecl`? In your first log messages it looks like the `mongo.so` extension wasn't installed in the expected directory ("/usr/lib/php5/20121212/"). When you tried the manual way, it seems like you're missing the PHP source. Have you tried `sudo apt-get install php5-dev php5-cli php-pear` before installing (as per the [MongoDB manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/php/#install-the-php-driver)).

Answer (score 0):

If you use use CLI command, you may need to add Mongo driver to the cli specific php.ini:

```
echo "extension=mongo.so" >> /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

For info, here is how I installed Mongo and mongo driver (according to [the doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)):

```
sudo -s
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
apt-get update
apt-get -y install mongodb-org
grep -q "extension=mongo.so" /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini || echo "extension=mongo.so" >> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
grep -q "extension=mongo.so" /etc/php5/cli/php.ini || echo "extension=mongo.so" >> /etc/php5/cli/php.ini && pecl install mongo
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry i couldn't try your solution because i already installed new version of Ubuntu day before yesterday. There seemed to be problem with my ubuntu. So i re-installed ubuntu 12.04 for fresh start and updated it to 14.04. I installed mongodb and it's php driver and it's working fine now.

Comment: No problem, let's hope my answer could help someone else later ;)

Comment: Yeah and that's for sure :)